# remote prod not found in git remotes

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So, git somehow sees remotes of all my apps, but fails to use them when asked to:

```
❯ git remote -v
...
prod    https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git (fetch)
prod    https://git.heroku.com/my-app.git (push)
...

❯ heroku run rails c -r prod --verbose
 ▸    remote prod not found in git remotes
```

At the same time, --application works fine

```
❯ heroku run rails c -a my-app
Running rails c on ⬢ my-app... ⣷ connecting, run.4544 (Standard-1X)
```

Comment: This question seems to be about heroku, not Git. Shouldn't it have different tags?

Comment: As torek stated, I believe this issue relates to heroku. You are invoking a heroku command, and if you executed git commands directly I don't believe you will have any issue with git

Comment: See this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/parity/issues/51).

Comment: Yup, looks like you are right guys

Answer (score 7):

So, I don't know what broke it, but re-running git:remote fixed it

```
heroku git:remote -r prod -a my-app-prod
```